# Slim upload file by directory file

Tags: slim

i have problem with file upload. i want to upload file by name or path file in local.
i tried to use

```
$app->post('/books/cover/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $path = "d:\\1.jpg";
    $file = basename($path);

$uploadedFile = $file;
if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $args["id"], $extension);

    $directory = $this->get('settings')['upload_directory'];
    $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);


    return $response->withJson(["status" => "failed", "data" => "0"], 200);
}
});
```

Comment: '$uploadedFile = $file;' means `$uploadedFile` is a string, so you can't call any member functions on it (like `->getError()` or `->moveTo()`). And the part of your question saying `I want to upload file by name or path file in local` is not clear. Please add more details. Is `d:\\1.jpg` a path on client's machine?

Comment: I understand the first part, it was very clear, thanks.
By any means, i wanted to set the directory on a fixed location, like e.g. d:\\1.jpg, that, or can i set the post $app->post('/books/cover/{id}' by the name of the file ?. thanks for the advice.